# AngularJS tabs and hotkeys combination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hotkeys, mousetrap

I am trying to use the hotkeys to change the tabs in AngularJS. I am new to AngularJS but i am sure it should be as simple as the code below. So when a hotkey is pressed, it is unable to change the tab activeness. It is basically doing nothing for now but when 't' is pressed, it should display the tab2 content.

I created a keybinding directive which invokes a function and uses Mousetrap to use the keyboard shortcuts.So when the hotkey 't' is pressed, I am able to invoke the function and change the tab active to true but I am unable to show the changes in the View.

#### This is my html file

```
 <div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">

 <keybinding on="t" invoke="hotkey()"></keybinding>
 <tabset>
  <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active">
   {{tab.content}}
  </tab>
 </tabset>
</div>
```

#### This is app.js file

```
  var app = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
  app.controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
  $scope.tabs = [
   { title:'Dynamic Title 1', content:'Dynamic content 1' },
   { title:'Dynamic Title 2', content:'Dynamic content 2'}
    ];

  $scope.hotkey = function(){
   $scope.tabs[1].active=true;
        }
  });

   app.directive('keybinding', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
     scope: {
         invoke: '&'
     },
    link: function (scope, el, attr) {
        Mousetrap.bind(attr.on, scope.invoke);
    }
 };
 });
```

Here's [a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1zzZKTDgDKM6GqHvr9DT?p=preview).

Comment: In this updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1zzZKTDgDKM6GqHvr9DT?p=preview)!, i am observing that the tab is changing but when there is some event or something clicked on that page. i am not sure why is that happening but when you press the hotkey 't' and then click on any of the links from the list the tab changes. Similarly after pressing the hotkey 't' and changing the tab by manually clicking you can see the bottom content is changing. What can be the reason for this ? I am not sure if I made myself clear